# how to display the selected row on kendo grid to the textbox

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am new to Kendo grids. I have a kendo grid that displays the Id,name,Email Id. So if a select a row that complete row should be displayed in the texboxes related to the fields(Id,name,Email).

Comment: Textboxes where in the grid on the screen somewhere else? What have you tried. Do you have a dojo or fiddle you can share to help aid the question?

Comment: Added the code. For the grid i tried to get the selected row. But dont how to get the selected row displayed on to the textboxes.

Comment: Added the screenshot. So once i selected the row those values should be displayed on the textboxes shown above

Comment: Are these textboxes being used as some form of editing screen? If so have you considered using the inbuilt editing features of the kendo grid i.e. inline, cell or pop up.

Comment: I dont want to edit those textboxes ..Once i get the selected row values over there i need to click on add so that new user will be created

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function to fill your form and an easy way to do it is to use the input ids as the same as the data properties. Example below:

```
change: function(e) {
    var dataItem = this.dataItem(this.select());
    fillForm(dataItem);
}
```

And the `fillForm` function:

```
var fillForm = function(dataItem) {
    var columns = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").options.columns;
    var form = $("form");

    for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        var field = columns[i].field;
        form.find("#" + field).val(dataItem[field]);
    }
}
```

This will run a *reflection* logic to fill automatically your form, being you form like:

```
<input type="text" id="Id" />
<input type="text" id="Name" />
<input type="text" id="LastName" />
```

And your data like:

```
{
    Id: 1,
    Name: "John",
    LastName: "Doe"
}
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/egUpI). I hope it helps.

Comment: @user3916062 define *Nothing*, please. Did you checked for errors, did you debugged it ?

Comment: its triggering the change event but not filling the form

Comment: @user3916062 did you debugged it? Did you checked the console? I can't help you if don't help me..

Comment: When i selected the row it filling the form but not displaying the values on the textboxes. I even used console.log ().. and saw it

Comment: Can you check this demo please and tell me where is the issue  http://dojo.telerik.com/egUpI/6

Comment: @user3916062 1- You form selector is wrong: `$("third")` should be `$("#third")`, as `third` is the `id`, so we use `#` to get it; 2- The function `fillForm` search for the form fields by the id and its case sensitive, so instead of `firstname` it should be `FirstName` as declared in your column's `field` property. http://dojo.telerik.com/egUpI/9

Comment: I got it working finally Thanks a lot for your demo :)

Comment: @user3916062 np, we are here to help. Don't forget to mark the answer if it helped.

Comment: @user3916062 forgot about this ?